# Room not accepting meeting in Exchange Online

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I created a room called "Sitzungsraum" in our M365 administration.

When sending meeting invitation to the room, they are not automatically accepted, neither displayed in related calendar.

I checked trough PowerShell the configuration and everything looks good.

Command 1:

```
Get-CalendarProcessing sitzungsraum@xxxxx| fl AutomateProcessing
```

Result 1:

```
AutomateProcessing : AutoAccept
```

Command 2:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "Sitzungsraum" | Select-Object RecipientTypeDetails
```

Result 2:

```
RecipientTypeDetails
--------------------
RoomMailbox
```

Comment: Lets check the Type. Could you update the question (not reply via comment) with the output of this command please `Get-Mailbox -Identity "Sitzungsraum" | Select-Object RecipientTypeDetails`

Comment: @jfrmilner Done